# update value from a table if from other two table values match

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to update around 800 rows and would like to update table_c it two values from table_A and table_b match. Table_a and table_c are related by value_id.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (VALUE_ID INTEGER, PERSON_ID INTEGER, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(15), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15));
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (VALUE_ID INTEGER, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(15), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15), ALIAS_ID INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE TABLE_C (VALUE_ID INTEGER, ALIAS_ID INTEGER, PERSON_ID INTEGER);
-----
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (VALUE_ID, PERSON_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (1, 6069, 'SMITH', 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (VALUE_ID, PERSON_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (2, 6111, 'ADAMS', 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (VALUE_ID, PERSON_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (3, 6117, 'ADAMS', 'SAM');
----
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, ALIAS_ID)
VALUES (4, 'SMITH', 'JOHN', 40856);
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, ALIAS_ID)
VALUES (5, 'ADAMS', 'JOHN', 3425);
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, ALIAS_ID)
VALUES (6, 'ADAMS', 'SAM', 40831);
-----
INSERT INTO TABLE_C (VALUE_ID, ALIAS_ID, PERSON_ID)
VALUES (7, 28, 6069);
INSERT INTO TABLE_C (VALUE_ID, ALIAS_ID, PERSON_ID)
VALUES (8, 1022, 6111);
INSERT INTO TABLE_C (VALUE_ID, ALIAS_ID, PERSON_ID)
VALUES (9, 40473, 6117)
```

---

I have tried using an update statement to accomplish this and/or an update statement but it does not work. Not sure if I need an IF/ELSE statement.

At the end, alias_id from table B and table C must be the same. So,that's why table_C is the one that will be updated.

This is what I have so far

```
UPDATE TABLE_C
SET C.ALIAS_ID = (SELECT B.ALIAS_ID 
                FROM TABLE_B B
                JOIN TABLE_A A 
                ON A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME AND A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME);
```

Comment: You've tagged this for SQL Server and Oracle SQL Developer.  Are you really using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database?  So you're looking for the SQL Server syntax rather than the Oracle syntax for a correlated update?

Comment: I'm using oracle-sql developer, and it is connected to a microsoft sql server database.

Comment: If there is a match between `TABLE_B` and `TABLE_A` then which specific record of `TABLE_C` should be updated?

Comment: the record to be updated is ALIAS_ID, from TABLE_C and TABLE_B

Comment: This is not a record, it's a column. `TABLE_C` has three records. What determines which one of these records is updated once a match is found?

Comment: It should be base on first_name, last_name and person_id between the three tables. it should be looking to match LAST_NAME and  FIRST_NAME from TABLE_A and TABLE_B. The link between TABLE_A and TABLE_C is PERSON_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query that uses `UPDATE ... FROM` SQL Server syntax:

```
UPDATE TABLE_C
SET ALIAS_ID = b.ALIAS_ID 
FROM TABLE_C AS c
INNER JOIN TABLE_A AS a ON c.PERSON_ID = a.PERSON_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS b ON a.FIRST_NAME = b.FIRST_NAME 
                           AND a.LAST_NAME = b.LAST_NAME
```

This might work for you in Oracle:

```
MERGE
INTO TABLE_C
USING (
   SELECT c.PERSON_ID AS pid, b.ALIAS_ID AS bAlias
   FROM TABLE_C AS c
   JOIN TABLE_A AS a ON c.PERSON_ID = a.PERSON_ID
   JOIN TABLE_B AS b ON a.FIRST_NAME = b.FIRST_NAME 
                       AND a.LAST_NAME = b.LAST_NAME       
)
ON (PERSON_ID = pid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET ALIAS_ID = bAlias;
```

Comment: It does makes sense. I'm not familiar with inner joins but I'm researching on that. Thank you for your assistance, I'll try the query.

Comment: It does retrieved that the sql command was not properly ended. I added the ";" at the end.

Comment: @bbetos It depends on the context the sql command is used: if used as a separate command or from within SSMS no semicolon delimeter is necessary.

Comment: well, if I add the semicolon or not still erroring out. do I need anything else on the set statement?

Comment: @bbetos I have tested my code against the schema / sample data you posted in the OP and it is working fine. If you are not using SQL Server as the target DB then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: i'm using oracle 11g not MS SQL Server. I really appreciate all your assistance.

Comment: @bbetos In this case I would definitely suggest adding `oracle` and `oracle11g` tags to your question.

Comment: @bbetos Please check the edit I made. I am a noob as far as Oracle is concerned, but this might work for you.

Comment: Your query works!!!! I just had to add Distinct on the select statement. You rock!!!